# Javascript to Measure Multiple Div Heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, measurement

I'm trying to build out an accordion menu with jQuery but am running into jumpy animations.  The jumpiness is caused by not setting a height for the div.  My problem is that each div is going to have a different height based on the contents; so the question is, how would I use javascript to look at each div with the class 'submenu', measure it's height, and set it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$('.submenu').each(function() {
  var divh = $(this).height();
  $(this).css('height', divh + 'px');
});
```

What I'm running into is that it only seems to measure one .submenu div and sets all of them to that height.  Thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using the `autoHeight` option of the accordion should solve this. You don't need to set each `div` height separately.

Comment: I don't get what's happening here - it looks like all you're doing is getting an element's height, and setting it to that height again. BTW, you can do `$(this).height(divh);`

Comment: @Zero21xxx I'll give the autoHeight option a try, though it looks like it will just determine the tallest section and set that height for all.

Comment: @NeXXeuS Each div has a different amount of content so I can't set a height for the 'submenu' class in general, so yes that's what I'm doing, but for multiple div's.  If the height is not set, the accordion animation is jumpy.

Comment: Also, it looks like there is only an issue when the div contains images.  If the div contains text the script above properly measures and sets the div height.

Comment: Believe I found the problem.  I had the above script in a $(document).ready() function which would only have loaded, and subsequently measured, the DOM.  Moved it to a $(window).load() function which would let it see the content and measure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe I found the problem.  I had the above script in a $(document).ready() function which would only have loaded, and subsequently measured, the DOM.  Moved it to a $(window).load() function which let it see the content and then measure the height.  As a point of clarification the .submenu class divs are the accordion divs.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.submenu').each(function() {
    var divh = $(this).height();
    $(this).css('height', divh + 'px');
  });

  $('.submenu').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose too look like this :

```
$('.submenu').each(function() {
  var divh = $(this).height();
  $('.divClass').css('height',  $('.divClass').height() + divh + 'px');
});
```

You need to always add the current div height in your for to your accordion div

Comment: The variable divh should do just that.

Comment: mhhh not sure I understand the problem, but i've edited the code, .divClass should be your div containing the accordion

Comment: Sorry, wasn't very clear, the .submenu class is the accordion div.  I found where the problem lies, will put it in as an answer.  Thanks for your help GregM!